# Eclipse development in a group

Tags: eclipse

I know that similar questions were already asked, but still I do not see a good solution.

Our group is developing using Eclipse (Java, C++, Groovy) on Linux.
We are using ClearCase with dynamic views.

I want that people will be able to use full eclipse workspace, prepared and maintained for me.
I need that list of projects (we generate eclipse projects from maven pom), code style preferences, save actions and many other things will be shared between people.

I tried to put workspace to source control, but it contains a lot of file, most of which are not relevant and it is hard to maintain on every change.

In IDEA it is simple - just one xml file for workspace, which easily can be placed to source control.

How can I do it with Eclipse?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share your project settings with source control, **do not put the whole workspace to source control, use project-specific settings**. If you select *Properties* from the context menu of a project you can see various preference pages where you can 'override' the workspace settings for this specific project. If you do this, a `.settings` folder is created within the project folder and you only have to commit this extra folder with the files within to share your project preferences.

For a java project you can share code templates, formatters, compiler settings, task tags and java editor save actions in this way. Combined this with the Team Project Sets lothar mentioned or with sharing only Maven POMs 'by hand' between developers can be a good start.

If you want more sophisticated 'workspace provisioning' you can try [Yoxos 5](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-5-beta/). It is currently in beta, but it is very promising. You can try it free with creating local profiles to see the capabilities of their workspace provisioning feature (including Team Project Sets and Preferences). However, for sharing Yoxos profiles you have to pay a subscription fee after the beta period.

Comment: I do all this now, but still it is not fully automated solution. I need that a developer will received changes in projects list, code style and save actions automatically.
I'll look to Yoxos. If it provides full profiles sharing, fee is not a problem.

BTW - will it store projects list in Yoxos or Eclipse settings only?

Comment: Yoxos shared profiles can contain plugins, preferences and has the ability of "project provisioning" at least with CVS and SVN. It may support ClearCase as well but you have to try it. Install and start the Yoxos Launcher, create a new profile with adding Yoxos customizer, Preferences provisioning and Projects provisioning components from Team/yoxos and your other plugins. Save that profile and run it - it will prepare a new "Eclipse" install and start with an empty workspace. Create the necessary projects, set up preferences and switch to Yoxos customizer perspective for editing the profile.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following the simplest solution:

1. Configure your workspace formatter, code style, etc.
2. Use `File->Export->General->Preferences`
3. Save those preferences to file
4. On any new workspace you work with `File->Import->General->Preferences`
5. You're done!

Comment: It will not solve my problem with workspace itself - which projects it contains. Also It will require from every team team member import preferences manually on every change.

Comment: you said you're creating project using maven. so adding all the projects is simply importing the parent pom.xml and all workspaces are defined

Comment: caution. Eclipse may store absolute paths in the preferences that may no longer work when imported by another user.

Comment: It is the same path because of usage of ClearCase dynamic views. However importing (and building ) all projects may take a while.
In development  with ClearCase views, a view is created usually for each feature so it is not a one time investment

Answer (score 0):

At the Eclipseday 2010 at Google [SonaType](http://sonatype.com/) [presented](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/9/9a/NextGenMaven.pdf) **Proviso**, a tool for developer onboarding. It seems to do exactly what you are asking for, so you might want to contact them. AFAIK the tool is not public yet, but you may be able to get into some beta program.

In case you can not get **Proviso** you can use [Project Set Files](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PSF) to define what projects are to be imported to your workspace.

You can also export and import preference settings, but be careful, as plugins may store file paths absolute in the preferences and these absolute paths may not work when imported by another user on another machine.